# FHIR Search recursive _include

Tags: recursion, hl7-fhir

Consider the below search request
http://host:port/base/DiagnosticOrder?patient.organization.name=MidValley&_count=10&_include=DiagnosticOrder:encounter:Encounter&_include:recurse=Encounter:practitioner:Practitioner&_include:recurse=Encounter:patient&_include:recurse=Patient:organization&_include:recurse=Patient:link&_include:recurse=Practitioner:organization

My questions below

1. Am I correct in interpreting the meaning of _include:recurse to be truly recursive? (like in the example above, we are recursing from DiagnosticOrder, through Patient and Practitioner until Organization
2. If the above is true, whats the official interpretation for including children of self-referencing children. For example, does the above query require the server to return organizations of linked patients of patients referenced in the encounters referenced in the orders?
   Sorry if I had complicated this beyond comprehension but below is a easily understandable representation(for programmers, sorry) of the query with computed ids, parent and depth without accounting to return organizations of linked patients.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"It is at the server's discretion how deep to recursively evaluate the inclusions". So there's no official answer to this, because it's pretty complex for a server. My view is that servers should do their best to be fully recursive, but also they have to figure out how to limit the amount of work they do. Since that's a tough problem, we haven't specified exactly how they do that.